# How to show products on magento 1.9 home page?

Tags: magento

> {{block type=”catalog/product_new” name=”home.catalog.product.new”
>   alias=”product_homepage” template=”catalog/product/new.phtml”}}

I am using this code to display my all products on homepage screen but still I am not able to view any product.

I am using this code on **CMS->pages->home page-> content**

Comment: type this widget snippet in home page, rather than copy paste it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have using magento c.E 1.9 version and this version already applied magento patch **SUPEE-6788.**

So,you need to remove catalog/product_list from white list

**System > Permissions > Blocks**

Add New Block

Block Name: catalog/product_list

Is Allowed : Yes

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow below step

you have to add this category_id="categoryId" in block

CategoryId = which Category's  products you want to show

OR

If above code does not help you please this one

Go to “CMS - Manage Pages” and select “Home Page” from the list of pages.

Use this code snippet to show one category on your front page:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}